# If I have 4 threads each accessing only 1 element of a list will I run into race conditions?

Tags: python, multithreading, list

If I have a list of say 4 items in python and each thread accesses only 1 item in the list, for example thread 1 assigned to the first item, thread 2 assigned to the 2nd item etc... will I have race conditions? do I need to use mutexes?

edit: I meant modify sorry, each thread will modify 1 item in the list. I added I was using python just because.

edit: @David Heffernan The list is a global because I need to send it somewhere every 1 second, so I have 4 threads doing the modification needed on each single item and every 1 second I send it somewhere over HTTP in the main thread.

Comment: IMHO it's better to use thread safe option like `Queue` then altering directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't have race conditions. CPython uses a global interpreter lock (GIL) to ensure atomicity of basic operations on data structures. However, the GIL also prevents Python code from really running concurrently - if you are looking to implement parallel execution, you probably want to explore [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html).

Comment: I think he's talking about each thread modifying different elements in the list.  I still think he's OK in that case.   I don't understand what CPython has to do with it, so the OP possibly doesn't either...

Comment: @GreenAsJade CPython is the default Python implementation maintained by Guido van Rossum and the Python development team. It is the most widely used Python implementation and the OP is almost certainly using it.

Comment: The GIL is not relevant. The GIL does not prevent data races.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The GIL does make it safe to operate on the same list (or dict, etc.) from different threads without corrupting it. No other synchronization mechanism in Python will do it for you.

Comment: So if one thread does `someList[0].doStuff()` and at the same time another thread does `someList[0].doStuff()`, you claim that the GIL means that there can be no data race?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You are interpreting my last comment as contradicting your previous one, when it was actually meant to supplant it and clarify the GIL reference in the answer. In other words, what I did say is that the GIL allows two threads to do things like `some_list.append("bla")` without messing up the list object internally, and without each list needing its own lock. That the GIL provides a semblance of atomicity to operations that fit inside an opcode is notorious in cpython, and a potential cause of bugs when running under GIL-less implementations.

Answer (score 1):

So long as each thread operates on different items in the list, then there will be no data races.

However, if you can partition the data off so cleanly, wouldn't it make more sense for each thread to operate on its own private data? Why have a list, visible outside the worker threads, containing items that are private to each thread. It would be cleaner, and easier to reason about the code if the data were private to the threads.

On the other hand your question edit suggests that you do have multiple threads accessing the same item of the list simultaneously. In which case there could well be a data race. Ultimately, without more detail nobody can say for sure whether or not your code is safe. In principle, so long as data is not shared between threads, then code will be threadsafe. But it's not possible to be sure that is the case with the problem description as stated.